# Adding new data through websocket when using store.query in route

Tags: ember.js, websocket, ember-data

My app is using a websocket service based on [ember-phoenix](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-phoenix#recommended-use) to push new records from the API to the store. I would like these new records to render in my template when they're added.

I have a route where the model hook returns a filtered query promise:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  get,
  inject,
} = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  socket: inject.service(),

  model(params) {
    return this.store.query('my-model', {filter: {date: params.date}})
  },

  afterModel() {
    get(this, 'socket').joinSchedule();
  },

  resetController() {
    get(this, 'socket').leaveSchedule();
  },

});
```

When new records are pushed to the store through the websocket, they are not rendered by my template because of how `store.query` works. If I change `store.query` to `store.findAll` the new records are rendered, but I want my route to only load a subset of all the records based on the date query param.

It seems like my only option is to just reload the route's model when a new record is pushed to the store. Is it possible to do this from the service? If not, is there a different approach I might want to explore?

The relevant parts of my socket service are below:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import PhoenixSocket from 'phoenix/services/phoenix-socket';

const {
  get,
  inject,
} = Ember;

export default PhoenixSocket.extend({
  session: inject.service(),
  store:   inject.service(),

  joinSchedule() {
    const channel = this.joinChannel(`v1:my-model`);

    channel.on('sync', (payload) => this._handleSync(payload));
  },

  _handleSync(payload) {
    get(this, 'store').pushPayload(payload);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
You can use [Ember.Evented](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html) to subscribe and dispatch event. I have created [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d7c3d3ab2f02b1d8729c2c3d45d28f9f?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C) for demonstration.

In `socket` service,

- `socket` should extend `Ember.Evented` class

  ```
  export default PhoenixSocket.extend(Ember.Evented, {
  ```
- After updating store, you can just trigger `myModelDataLoaded` which will dispatch all the functions subscribed to `myModelDataLoaded`.

  ```
   _handleSync(payload) {
          get(this, 'store').pushPayload(payload);
          this.trigger('myModelDataLoaded'); //this will call the functions subscribed to myModelDataLoaded.        
      }
  ```

In Route,

- You can subscribe to `myModelDataLoaded`

```
afterModel() {
        get(this, 'socket').joinSchedule();
        get(this, 'socket').on('myModelDataLoaded', this, this.refreshRoute); //we are subscribing to myModelDataLoaded
    }
```

- Define refreshRoute function and call `refresh` function.

  ```
     refreshRoute() {
          this.refresh(); //forcing this route to refresh
      }
  ```
- To avoid memory leak need to `off` subscribtion, you can do it either in `resetController` or `deactivate` hook.

  ```
  resetController() {
      get(this, 'socket').leaveSchedule();
      get(this, 'socket').off('myModelDataLoaded', this, this.refreshRoute);
  }
  ```

**Option 2**.
You can watch store using peekAll with observer and refresh route.

In your controller,
 1. Define `postModel` computed property which will return live record array.
 2. Define `postModelObserver` dependant on `postModel.[]` this will ensure whenever store is updated with new row, it will be observed by `myModelObserver` and it will send action `refreshRoute` to route . where we will call `refresh`. As you know this will call `beforeModel`, `model`, `afterModel` method.

As you know computed property is lazy, when you are accessing it only then it will be computed. so if you are not using it in template, then just add `this.get('myModel')` in `init` method

**Controller file**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const { computed } = Ember;
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.get('postModel');//this is just to trigger myModel computed property
    },
    postModel: computed(function() {
        return this.get('store').peekAll('post');
    }),
    postModelObserver: Ember.observer('postModel.[]', function() {
        this.send('refreshRoute');
    })
});
```

**Route file**  - define action `refreshRoute` for refreshing, since `refresh` is available only in route.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
    get,
    inject,
} = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    socket: inject.service(),
    model(params) {
        return this.store.query('my-model', { filter: { date: params.date } })
    },

    afterModel() {
        get(this, 'socket').joinSchedule();
    },

    resetController() {
        get(this, 'socket').leaveSchedule();
    },
    actions:{
        refreshRoute() {
            this.refresh();
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I ended up doing what you proposed in option 1 based on the response that @xoma posted above, but I'll give you credit since you took the time to document it for folks in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger an event from your websocket service when you receive a message on the socket, then subscribe to it in your route and then call refresh() to reload your model.
There is also https://github.com/ember-data/ember-data-filter - which retuns live array.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a better way, but one way to do with your existing code is using a callback.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
 get,
 inject,
} = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  socket: inject.service(),

  model(params) {
    return this.store.query('my-model', {filter: {date: params.date}})
  },

  afterModel() {
    let cb = (myModelRecord) => {
      this.get('model').push(myModelRecord);
    };
    get(this, 'socket').joinSchedule(cb);
  },

  resetController() {
    get(this, 'socket').leaveSchedule();
  },

});
```

Call callback method in socket service,

```
 import Ember from 'ember';
 import PhoenixSocket from 'phoenix/services/phoenix-socket';

 const {
   get,
   inject,
 } = Ember;

 export default PhoenixSocket.extend({
   session: inject.service(),
   store:   inject.service(),

   joinSchedule(cb) {
     const channel = this.joinChannel(`v1:my-model`);

     channel.on('sync', (payload) => cb(this._handleSync(payload)));
   },

  _handleSync(payload) {
    return get(this, 'store').pushPayload(payload);
  },
});
```